# jQuery UI 1.8.22 with jQuery 1.8 doesn't have text in dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I went to check if the recently released jQuery 1.8 (stable) would be compatible with my current project in development, and to my surprise this is the first thing I saw:

[image]

It is a surprise to me as I had already upgraded to jQuery UI 1.8.22, which according to its [release post](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/07/jquery-ui-1-8-22/), is compatible with jQuery 1.8.

The callback functions are called according, but the buttons have no `textNode`s as one can see in a DOM inspector:

[image]

The solutions which I've found so far are either:

1. Downgrade back to jQuery 1.7.2 (I would like to use the latest jQuery version in my page though)
2. Upgrade to jQuery UI 1.9.0pre (it's not stable)
3. Use an `open` handler or manually edit the HTML of the dialog to include my desired text. Seems like a lot of unneeded hassle for a bug in their source.

**Am I missing something or is this an actual bug?**

Here's the fiddle which I used for the demo:

### [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/a8rqJ/)

And the code for future reference:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="foo" title="Dialog title">Dialog text</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#foo').dialog({
    buttons: {
        Yes: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); },
        No: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
    }
});
```

Comment: No errors in the console and works fine when switching back to 1.7.2. Bug?

Comment: @j08691 Exactly. I'd submit a report to their bugtracker but I don't have experience with it and I want to make sure it's actually a bug. Even though it's quite evident, I tend to overlook simple things.

Comment: I've seen a few things today floating around about this. Might want to look around and then just submit the report.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, was it just about the dialog buttons or including other parts of the UI as well?

Comment: The jsFiddle doesn't allow you to select the jqueryUI... does that mean that it is autoloading?  It is possible that jsFiddle doesn't have it updated yet.  I haven't downloaded a copy to try it myself.

Comment: @TimWithers I'm using Microsoft's CDN to load jQuery UI 1.8.22. I've tried with the jQuery CDN as well. You can see the files in the "Manage Resources" part in the left panel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### **EDIT:**

Here's the [BugTracker ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8484).

A much simpler solution is to use this snippet after including the jQuery library:

```
if ( $.attrFn ) { $.attrFn.text = true; }
```

### [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/a8rqJ/14/)

This issue should be fixed when jQuery UI 1.8.23 is released. Credits to scott.gonzalez from the BugTracker ticket page.

**EDIT**: This has been fixed in [UI 1.8.23](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js).

---

**My old solution:**
(use it if you have problems with the one above)

I've made a temporary fix for this issue (until a new stable version of either UI or core is release).

There's a bug with jQuery 1.8 interacting with jQuery UI 1.8.22 which stores the text in the parent `button`'s `text` attribute instead of creating a `textNode` inside the `span.ui-button-text`:

[image]

Use this snippet after initializing jQuery UI `dialog`s or any other interface which has this UI button bug:

```
//iterate through all UI button text spans in the document
$('.ui-button-text').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() == '') //if it has no text (bugged)
        $this.text($this.parent().attr('text')); //sets the text which was passed
});
```

### [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/a8rqJ/13/)

The script checks if the UI button has no text before doing anything, so it's harmless to keep even if you forget it there when upgrading to future non-bugged versions of core/UI.

If you have a better solution or information on this bug I'll glad accept it. `=]`

Note that you can downgrade to jQuery 1.7.2 or use a pre-release of UI 1.9.0 as mentioned in the question if you can't wait for a stable release and still want to use the latest stable versions.

Comment: @j08691 Yup, I should browse their BugTracker first next time. `:P` Hopefully this will be a good reference 'til they release a new stable build (UI 1.8.23 should have this fixed).

Comment: Just ran into this today as well. Breaks with the [] syntax for buttons option as well. Thanks for the good question and answer