# jQuery UI 1.9.1 with jQuery 1.9.1 displaying no text in dialog button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

For some reason the modal that is being displayed is not showing the required text.

I am setting the buttons like so:

```
buttons: {
    "Update": function() {
    }
}
```

I have tried setting:

```
 if ( $.attrFn ) { $.attrFn.text = true; }
```

Which this question mentioned ([jQuery UI 1.8.22 with jQuery 1.8 doesn't have text in dialog buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907661/jquery-ui-1-8-22-with-jquery-1-8-doesnt-have-text-in-dialog-buttons)) however, this also does not work.

The modal button looks like so:

[image]

The DOM elements is like so:

```
 <button type="button" text="Update" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
     <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
</button>
```

as you can see **text="Update"** is set. So it knows what it is supposed to be setting, however the span is empty.

any suggestions?

Comment: you used UI 1.9.2. not 1.9.1

Comment: I am not able to update js either...

Comment: well there is clearly a bug with the versions I offered. I'm not sure why the downvote.

Comment: You're right, it does appear to be a bug in jqUI 1.9.1. I'd suggest upgrading. It's rather outdated now anyway. Not sure why you've been downvoted.

Comment: prob downvoted because the dude who replied first used a different version, posted his answer as though you were wrong and others just read that and took it verbatim. Don't stress, just hope you code better than and more diligently than some people read and respond. Gunna post you a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this after you call the modal

```
 // Dirty Fix, remove when better answer from Stack Overflow

 $('.ui-button-text').each(function(i){
     $(this).html($(this).parent().attr('text'))
 });
```

I can't offer you a solution as to why this happened I'm afraid. You should find one and replace this hack.

peace out